# react-helmet Meteor Server Side Rendering

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-redux, react-router, react-helmet

I want to implement react-helmet on Meteor. **The client side works fine and I can see the tags on the Inspect Element** - but how to render it on server side for SEO? I do not understand the documentation.

```
ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Handler />);
const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
```

My Code is as follows

**index.html (client)**

```
<head>
   <body>
     <div id="target" />
   </body>
</head>
```

**main.js (client)**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { renderRoutes } from '../imports/startup/client/routes.jsx'

Meteor.startup(() => {
  render(renderRoutes(), document.getElementById('target'));
});
```

I'm using React-Router to render the element to the "target"

**main.js (server)**

How to get the tags from the server.

```
import { onPageLoad } from 'meteor/server-render';  
Meteor.startup(() => {

  onPageLoad((sink) => {  

    const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
    sink.appendToHead(helmet.meta.toString());
    sink.appendToHead(helmet.title.toString());
  });

});
```

**On the about code `helmet.meta.toString()` returns empty.** I know we need to pass something to let the helmet know the meta tags. But how to do that

Can someone help me understand what I need to write on the server to get this working? Everything except that is working fine.

Comment: Any help anyone pls :( !

Comment: Do you see the html tags of your components when you view source ?

Comment: @Muljayan Just the head and body. Not individual body tags. But I just need to append the meta tags generated by helmet on to the server side rendering of the page. How can I do that using the above files.

Comment: https://blog.meteor.com/meteor-platform-is-still-alive-5f6426644555 This blog on the meteor blog might be helpful. It has an example to use react-helmet

Comment: `sink.renderIntoElementById('app', renderToString(<App location={sink.request.url} />));`

Comment: I have a react-router setup

Comment: @Muljayan So I cannot have an App component like that

Comment: @Muljayan I've updated the code on the question. Pls see

Comment: I'm not able to find a solution yet. Lets see if someone else might know whats wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found the solution :

The code on the **main.js (server)** should be the following

```
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import  {renderRoutes}  from '../imports/startup/both/routes.jsx'

// ...

onPageLoad((sink) => {  
    const context = {};
    const app = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
      <StaticRouter location={sink.request.url} context={context}>
        {renderRoutes()}
      </StaticRouter>
   );

    sink.renderIntoElementById('react-root', app);
    const helmet = Helmet.renderStatic();
    sink.appendToHead(helmet.meta.toString());
    sink.appendToHead(helmet.title.toString());
  });
```

Hope it helps someone who might run into the same issue in the future. :)